# iOS getting width of the face by front camera without camera UI

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-image, ios-camera

Rightnow i am developing an app to detect distance between the user's face and device by using front camera with AVFoundation and Core - image framework.

For face detection i got a sample code (squarecam) from apple website
          https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html

In this example they are using AvFoundation to control the camera and core - image to detect face with Camera UI. 
  But i need these process without camera UI. Is it possible to hide camera UI using AVFoundation framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIImagePickerViewController` and set `showsCameraControls` property to `NO` and provide your own user interface using `cameraOverlayView`. here is the example https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html

or can use [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/) classes, refer `AVCamCaptureManager` and `AVCamRecorder` classes. here is the demo by apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112

Comment: Suhit thanks for your response.I have checked the links which you mentioned, in that they are changing the camera controls but not hiding the whole UI. In my case i want to open camera but UI should not be shown.

Comment: in the photopicker they have created the custom interface, you can hide controls if you want or customise it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to hide the camera preview while still getting a video feed from the camera?

In that case, I believe you can keep using the code in squarecam and simply hide the PreviewLayer.

You will still get the

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

so you can get the image.

However, I would recommend you find the sample code for Stachecam and look at the AVMetaDataOutput implementation for real-time face detection